# Wordpress site hacked don't know how

Tags: wordpress

I have recently developed a website

http://www.nisargarws.com

Unfortunately this is hacked by someone.
I go through all the files of directories I didn't find anything anynomys .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because its Wordpress you should check the themes directory under wp-content and see "hacked" content.

Also enter the database for the users table delete any unknown users. Ensure your account entry under users is your email and then access http://www.nisargarws.com/wp-admin/, reset the password and update Wordpress.

It could also be that the user gained cPannel access if that's what you are using, change that password too.

If the index.php file has been edited, download a new copy of Wordpress form Wordpress.org and replace that file.

Comment: thanks Alex i will replace the wp directory with my backup file

Comment: Report your solution to Wordpress, because there are many sites on the Internet with this issue. Let me know what fixes it.